# Get records from a table where an array of deleted_organization_id does not contain organization id using eloquent laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have one table 'posts' it normally have column such as 'id, title, content, ..., deleted_for_organization'

Other table: organization with id,name, description

User: id,name,email,password,organization_id

Currently, I am storing organization id in deleted_for_organization column in json array format such as [1,2,3]. This refers that this post is deleted for those organization and should not be visible for any member of organization.

Now, whenever a request is made to load all posts, I want to only those posts which are not deleted for their organization using eloquent.

Is this possible, or do I need to create another pivot table to maintain relationship of something like many-many.

While going through laravel eloquent documents, I came across

`$posts = App\Post::whereDoesntHave('comments', function ($query) {
    $query->where('content', 'like', 'foo%');
})->get();`

But, i could not figure out, either this fits to my problem or not.

Comment: though i don't recommend to use like this structure, laravel 5.6  has `whereJsonContain`  and `whereJsonDoesntContain` that you can look.  `App\Post::whereJsonDoesntContain('deleted_for_organization', $orgId)->get()`

Comment: @rkj could you provide me the link of documentation of `whereJsonContain`

Comment: it whereJsonNotContains. And here https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/55a30f9876aee6c312548503d55e85112186609a/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are looking.

`$posts = Post::whereRaw("not json_contains(deleted_for_organization , '[".Auth::user()->organization_id."]') OR deleted_by_org is NULL")->get();`

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to retrieve all of the posts that have not been deleted. Then pass $undeletedPosts on to your blade view file and foreach() loop through them to manipulate the data however you'd like. This should work, let me know if it works for you.

```
$userID = 10; //dynamically get user's ID instead of hard coding it
$organizationID = $user->where('id', $userID)->first()->organization_id;
$deletedPosts = $posts->select('id')->where('deleted_for_organization', $organizationID)->toArray();

$undeletedPosts = $posts->whereNotIn('deleted_for_organization', $deletedPosts)->get();
```